# Wifi REST API GET call - how to concatenate and pass URL parameters?

Tags: wifi

I'm not too familiar with the Arduino C++ language, but I would like to get this native code to work.

In curl this works:

> curl "http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment?text=i+feel+great&outputMode=json&apikey=my-apikey"^C

So I am trying to use a WiFi client for the same request but it seems the passing and parsing of the URL parameters is causing a problem.

```
sprintf(request,"/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment?apikey=%s&text=%s&outputMode=%s","31adba6dfc3a879b88762f50efc9f892bd573207", "i+feel+great", "json");
Serial.println(request);
```

When I print the request, everything after the & gets truncated.

```
  char serverName[] = "access.alchemyapi.com";
  if(client.connect(serverName,port) == 1)
  {
    sprintf(outBuf,"GET %s HTTP/1.1",page);
    client.println(outBuf);
    sprintf(outBuf,"Host: %s",serverName);
    client.println(outBuf);
    client.println(F("Connection: close\r\n"));
  }
```

This works (HTTP status 200, though with missing parameters error from the API service) if I only pass in 1 parameter.

Comment: How is "request" defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating the string data in memory before sending it shouldn't be necessary. Instead, you should just be able to use `client.print()` (or equivalent) to output each part of the request in sequence. For example:

```
client.print("GET ");
client.print(page);
client.print(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");

client.print("Host: ");
client.print(serverName);
client.print("\r\n");

// etc.
```

That should let you output any combination of HTTP headers you need.